# Why the footer page number is not being removed with `fancyhdr`

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, footer

I want to remove the footer from my document but the page number won't disappear. I tried to follow some suggestions from other questions, and it should work but it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

`Version: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=latex) restricted \write18 enabled.`

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\author{Somebody}
\title{The quick brown fox}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[L]{Test}
\maketitle

\chapter{Test One}

I know you followed me. Don't look so surprised.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

With the `book` class, the chapter introduction page uses the `plain` page style so that needs redefining:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[L]{Test}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Removes head rule

\fancypagestyle{plain}{% redefining plain pagestyle
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyhead{}
    \fancyfoot[L]{Test}
}

\author{Somebody}
\title{The quick brown fox}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Test One}

I know you followed me. Don't look so surprised.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solves perfectly.