# Why is \thispagestyle{empty} being ignored? Eliminate heading on page with figure

Tags: fancyhdr, pagestyle

`\thispagestyle{empty}` is being ignored, that is, I still see the heading (partially obscured on the pages with images; not obscured at all on the pages with captions). Any ideas why? I would guess that I'm making a very elementary mistake, perhaps issuing `thispagestyle{empty}` too late?

(I am using XeLaTeX.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=5.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{dpfloat}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\setlength{\headheight}{25.1pt}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage \hspace{1cm} \leftmark}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark \hspace{1cm} \thepage}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\fillast}
{{\Huge \thechapter}}
{1ex minus .1ex}
{\large \thispagestyle{empty}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{3pc}{*3}{*2}[3pc]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{leftfullpage}
\newgeometry{top=1cm,bottom=0cm}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{plate I.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\restoregeometry
\end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{fullpage}
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Caption on facing page
\end{center}
\end{fullpage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{leftfullpage}
\newgeometry{top=1cm,bottom=0cm}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{plate II.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\restoregeometry
\end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{fullpage}
\begin{center}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Caption on facing page
\end{center}
\end{fullpage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Here are my two images:

[image: plate I.jpg]

[image: plate II.jpg]

Comment: Try my answer to a similar question (redefining `plain` page style) and let us know if it works, perhaps because you are using the `book` class the first page of chapters is not having the `fancyhdr` style: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/689021/273733

Comment: read the documentation of fancyhdr. There is a section called 19 Special page layout for float pages.

Comment: Without testing, I guess that a figure float is not a good place for the `\thispagestyle` command, because you place it  "this page" (i.e, somewhere in the source") but the float  could end in "that page"  (i.e, far away  in the PDF version of text) that is out of the scope of "this page". Floats can float,  sometimes nothing, sometimes only a paragraph or so, others times to another page even some pages away. Forcing it to move to a page of floats (`[p]` option) very probably you will run into the last case.

Comment: you can not use `\thispagestyle` inside a figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer is indebted to Ulrike Fischer's comment.

Use

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\iffloatpage{}{\thepage \hspace{1cm} \leftmark}}
```

and

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\iffloatpage{}{\leftmark \hspace{1cm} \thepage}}
```

instead of

```
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage \hspace{1cm} \leftmark}
```

and

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\leftmark \hspace{1cm} \thepage}
```